# CodeIgniter: Delete data from MySQL DB using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a project, where inside admin panel I have a table for enquiries and I want to allow admin to delete any of them. 
My view code is as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delbtn" onclick="delenquiry(<?php echo $value->id;?>)">Delete this Enquiry</button>
```

My ajax code is:

```
function delenquiry(id) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'loginc/delenq',
            type: 'post',
            data: id,
            success: function () {
                alert('ajax success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ajax failure');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert(id + " not deleted");
    }
}
```

Controller code is:

```
 public function delenq() {

        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->logins->delenqs($id);
    }
```

And model code is:

```
public function delenqs($id) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('enquiry');

}
```

I looked for answers, but didn't got any. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you getting any errors? any error message in the console?

Comment: @mdamia no, i am getting and alert saying "ajax success"

Comment: var_dump($id); or post data? are you getting the id?

Comment: you have ajax syntax error. data : `{ id:id }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass id from your ajax request change

```
 data: id,
```

To

```
 data: {id:id},
```

for data you must provide an array .
for example =>   `data:{name_params:10}` 
you can get data in php `$id = $this->input->post('name_params');`
and the value $id will be = 10

Comment: thanks, it worked. Can you tell me what mistake did I make?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that your ID is not an available key in your `POST`. You would need to define `{id : id}`. However, I think this makes more sense from an MVC approach:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'loginc/delenq/'+ id, //maintains the (controller/function/argument) logic in the MVC pattern
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(a,b,c){
        console.log(a,b,c);
    }
});
```

Then you can expect an argument to your controller function:

```
public function delenq($id){
    if($id)
        return $this->logins->delenqs($id);
    return false;
}
```

And finally, your model can get a little fixer upper so that it properly returns as well.

```
public function delenqs($id) {
    $this->db->delete('enquiry', array('id' => $id));
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 1 ? true:false;

}
```